# How to get the auth URL from an OmniAuth provider without redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth, omniauth-twitter

How do you get the URL that OmniAuth redirect to when you go to `/auth/twitter`?

I am building an API server and just want to pass the URL in JSON to the client so it can do whatever it needs to with the URL.

I think what I want is the result of the strategy's `request_phase` as that looks to be the auth URL, but how do I get that in a new controller so I can do:

```
class MyOauthController < ApplicationController
  # GET /my_oauth/signin/twitter.json
  def signin
    url = ???
    render json: {signin_url: url}
  end
```

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Omniauth provides a helper function for you:

```
user_omniauth_authorize_path(key)
# for your case
user_omniauth_authorize_path("twitter")
```

Check out [their Devise overview](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a clean way to do this?

Not directly, no - vanilla OmniAuth doesn't generate routes by itself. It uses something called "Rack middleware" which would intercept request outside of Ruby on Rails context and hence wouldn't need a Rails route to function.

The Evan's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41271180/23497002) is dependent on Devise gem, which is not strict requirement for OmniAuth (you may have it bundled & loaded or may not have it).

A *cleaner alternative* to blatant copy & pasting the relative route around may be some wrapper method/helper that could contain `"/auth/twitter"` reference to a single place/be more DRY.